# Path name with spaces causing errors

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, windows-7-x64, irb

I have installed ruby 2.1.6 32 bit on Windows 7 64 bit. I have also installed the selenium webdriver gem. I am trying to assign the path of the chrome exe and read some tips on the net to use PROGRA~1 instead of Program Files x86 and got the follwoing issue

```
 irb(main):018:0> Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path ="C:\PROGRA~1\Google   \Chrome\>
    SyntaxError: (irb):18: Invalid escape character syntax
    ...ome.path ="C:\PROGRA~1\Google\Chrome\Application"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually using the double-quotes to denote the string. The `\` are being used as escape characters rather than backslashes.

Use single quotes instead:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:\PROGRA~1\Google\Chrome\Application'
```

As well, the space in the path will be valid:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application'
```

As an aside, I think you might be using the `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path=` incorrectly. You want it to reference the "chromedriver.exe" not "chrome.exe".

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to keep in mind is that if you are trying to access any type of network drive you must use double quotes and use escape sequences correctly. "X:\folder\folder\folder\file". If you are staying local single quotes are fine.